# Use rvest to extract html table

Tags: r, xpath

I am a new learner for R, I am interested in using rvest to extract html table and submit html forms.

Now, I want to get some useful information from a Chinese Website.  The url is:

http://caipiao.163.com/award/cqssc/20160513.html

I am using Windows 10 Professional with RStudio Version 0.99.896, I use Google Chrome as the web browser with XPATH helper addon.

I want to extract the main html table from the Chinese site, it contains 120 groups of information about the lottery winning number.  The first one (001) is: 98446 and  the last one (120) is: 01798; I want to extract only the numbers (001) to (120) and the winning numbers: 98446 to 01798.

I used XPATH helper and Chrome web development to get the XPATH.

I think the XPATH for the information I want is:

```
//html/body/article[@class='docBody clearfix']/section[@id='mainArea']/div[@class='lottery-results']/table[@class='awardList']/*[@id="mainArea"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]
```

But when I run the following code in RStudio, I can not get the result I want.
The following is my code:

```
> library(rvest)
Loading required package: xml2
> url <- "http://caipiao.163.com/award/cqssc/20160513.html"
> xp <- "//html/body/article[@class='docBody clearfix']/section    [@id='mainArea']/div[@class='lottery-results']/table[@class='awardList']/*[@id='mainArea']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]"
> 
> x <- read_html(url)
> y <- x %>% html_nodes(xpath=xp)
> y
{xml_nodeset (0)}

>
```

Please take a look at my code and let me know if I made any mistakes.  You can simply ignore those unknown Chinese characters, they are not important, I just want to get the numbers.

Thanks!
John

Answer (score 5):

It's not necessary to use such a precise target selector since there's only one `table` element (as the other answerer also pointed out). But you don't need to leave `rvest` behind:

```
library(rvest)

URL <- "http://caipiao.163.com/award/cqssc/20160513.html"

pg <- read_html(URL)
tab <- html_table(pg, fill=TRUE)[[1]]

str(tab)

## 'data.frame': 40 obs. of  39 variables:
##  $ 期号    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
##  $ 开奖号码: chr  "9 8 4 4 6" "1 8 3 1 6" "2 9 3 5 6" "1 4 5 8 0" ...
##  ....
```

(SO is interpreting some of the unicode glyphs as spam so I had to remove the other columns).

The second column gets compressed via post-page-load javascript actions, so you'll need to clean that up a bit if that's the one you're going for.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the function `readHTMLTable` from package `XML` to get the whole table, as in your website there is only one `<table>` element:

```
install.packages("XML)
library(XML)
url <- "http://caipiao.163.com/award/cqssc/20160513.html"
lotteryResults <- as.data.frame(readHTMLTable(url))
```

Then you can just do some cleansing procedures, subsetting and using rbind to get a data.frame with 2 columns and 120 observations.

Comment: did you run that code? I'm not sure the OP realizes there's some post-processing in JS to make contiguous #'s

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, your solution seems to be rater good.  However, my R level is not good enough, I can see the result, like: 1      001 9 8 4 4 6 <U+5C0F><U+53CC>...  But how I can extract the '001' and '9 8 4 4 6' and get rid of other useless info?